# Is there a way to display all new object's properties?

Tags: javascript, object, console.log

Say I have this code:

```
 x = "abcde";
 y = new String(x);
```

when I `console.log(y)` it  it only returns the following:
     `String {0: "a", 1: "b", 2: "c", 3: "d", 4: "e", length: 5, [[PrimitiveValue]]: "abcde"}`

But still I can say `y.charAt(0);` and it would return `"a"` so where's this `charAt` method hiding? and how can I see it in the console.log?

Comment: Haven't you noticed `__proto__` in console?

Comment: you can use a for-in loop to hit all the inherited properties that the console hides.

Comment: @saptal `console.log(y.__proto__);` returns `String {length: 0, [[PrimitiveValue]]: ""}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`y` gets `charAt` from `String.prototype`, which on many browsers you'll see in the console as [`__proto__`](https://people.mozilla.org/~jorendorff/es6-draft.html#sec-__proto__-property-names-in-object-initializers). In the console, if it's there, you can probably expand `__proto__` to see the `String.prototype` properties (and then expand *its* `__proto__` to see `Object.prototype` properties).

The `__proto__` property is being added to JavaScript in ES6, but it may not be present on an object, because it comes from `Object.prototype`, and it's possible for an object *not* to be backed (directly or indirectly) by `Object.prototype` (see below, under the bar).

If you want to access those properties in *code* — including code you use in the console to inspect objects — you can use [`Object.getPrototypeOf`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.2.3.2) (which works whether the object has `__proto__` or not) and [`Object.getOwnPropertyNames`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.2.3.4). The former gives you the object's prototype, and the latter gives you **all** of the property names of that object (even if they're non-enumerable).

So for a comprehensive list of all properties:

```
function getAllProperties(obj) {
    var props = [];

    while (obj) {
        props.push.apply(props, Object.getOwnPropertyNames(obj));
        obj = Object.getPrototypeOf(obj);
    }

    return props;
}
```

**Live Example:**

```js
var x = "abcde";
var y = new String(x);
snippet.log(getAllProperties(y).join(", "));

function getAllProperties(obj) {
  var props = [];

  while (obj) {
    props.push.apply(props, Object.getOwnPropertyNames(obj));
    obj = Object.getPrototypeOf(obj);
  }

  return props;
}
```

```html
<!-- Script provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<script src="http://tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>
```

---

How would an object *not* be backed by `Object.prototype` directly or indirectly, but still have a prototype? Like this:

```
var p = Object.create(null);   // p has no prototype
var o = Object.create(p);      // o has p as a prototype
console.log("__proto__" in o); // false, __proto__ comes from Object.prototype, 
                               // which isn't in o's prototype chain
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is how you can find it in console

[image]